# Use network with usb link

Tags: java, android, network-programming, usb, wifi

I wish to know if it's possible to use network(internet for example) of my computer on android application with usb link and so don't use wi-fi.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/191930/Android-Usb-Port-Forwarding
I'm not sure if i well understood your question. If this is not the solution, try to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)
In fact, I wish to know if a android application can get access to network through the USB cable without need one application on computer.

I mean you plug your device in USB, launch your android application to get network, without an application on PC.